# Open a text file and find a word and point to that word

Tags: java, text

I need to open a log file (.txt) and to go to that specific word.

Ex:- If im searching **"MyTextWord"** in the text file, it should open the default editor and go to the word **"MyTextWord"**.

If it's in the 100th line it should go there, so that it shows 100th line and onwards.

Can it be done for linux and windows?

Comment: Are you wanting to highlight the word or put the cursor there?

Comment: @Kyte yes, highlight or put the cursor there.

Comment: Next question, are you displaying the text file in a window of your own creation? Say, in a JTextPane/Panel?

Comment: @Kyte no. im using the default text editor of the os. (edited question too)

Answer (score 0):

I think, past a few days I was developing a simple project which involved the same thing.

You can use Scanner to scan the file for the data. And then loop through it to get the data.

I would paste the code here and I would share the post link with you, so that if you need any further info, you can get it from there.

You can pass the string as the parameter to the method.

```
String character = sc.next(); // read character...
// Find the character
System.out.println("Searching now...");
getCharacterLocation(character); // here is the parameter as character
```

File reading function is below:

```
File file = new File("res/File.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
int lineNumber = 0;
int totalLines = 0;
boolean found = false;
// First get the total number of lines
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
   totalLines++;
   sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Line looping! For Total Lines variable.");
}
int[] lineNumbers = new int[totalLines];
int lineIndex = 0;
System.out.println("Searching in each line...");
sc.close();
sc = new Scanner(file);
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
     // Until the end
     /* Get each of the character, I mean string from
     * each of the line... */
     String characterInLine = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
     if(characterInLine.indexOf(character.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
       found = true;
     }
     lineNumber++;
     if(sc.hasNextLine())
       sc.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Searching complete, showing results...");
// All done! Now post that.
if(found) {
   // Something found! :D
   System.out.print("'" + character + "' was found in the file!");
} else {
// Nope didn't found anything!
System.out.println("Sorry, '" + 
character + "' didn't match any character in file  .");
}
sc.close();
```

Yes, I know its a bit messed up code, because I like writing comments and I like to get information of what ever process is being executing and has done executing.

To get the whole code for this, go to the link below.

http://basicsofwebdevelopment.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/scanning-file-for-particular-string-or-character-searching/

Comment: i need the text file(default text editor) to open and cursor should go to that word, lets say 100th line it is in, then cursor should go there so we start with the 100th line.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which editor is the default, yes it is doable. For example if you use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) you can open files with `sublime somefile.txt:X:Y` where `X` is the line number and `Y` is the column or character position. I'm sure most decent editors have similar capabilities, I'm not sure if there is any standards for this though.

So basically you would have to pre-process the log in question to find the line number and character position, start the editor with some additional parameters. As far as `default editor` goes, that would be more difficult since they probably don't share the same parameters for specifying line/column. And some, such as windows notepad probably don't support this kind of thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a way to open NotePad](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-open-notepad) for windows. I'm not sure if you are able to search and select text within the process itself...I'll check into that.

You can also check out the [Desktop javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).